Cant access kubernetes openfunction
So Im trying to run a function on Openfunctions in my kubernetes but when i run kubectl get routes I get a url like this http://serving-pjqnl-ksvc-kfd2q.default.example.com but its not accessible. This is my function.yaml
apiVersion: core.openfunction.io/v1beta2
kind: Function
metadata:
  name: python-sample
spec:
  version: "v1.0.0"
  image: "davidbackxdataroots/sample-python-func:v1"
  imageCredentials:
    name: push-secret
  build:
    builder: "openfunction/gcp-builder:v1"
    env:
      GOOGLE_FUNCTION_TARGET: "hello_world"
      GOOGLE_FUNCTION_SIGNATURE_TYPE: "http"
      GOOGLE_FUNCTION_SOURCE: "main.py"
    srcRepo:
      url: "https://github.com/Davidbackx/minio.git"
      sourceSubPath: "/"
      revision: "main"
  serving:
    template:
      containers:
        - name: function
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3 
    triggers:
      http:
        port: 8080

This succeeds and this returns an internal end external endpoint. Then i create a curl pod like this kubectl run curl --image=radial/busyboxplus:curl -i --tty
where I then curl the internal endpoint and this returns the expected output in this case just a simpel "hello world". But only when I get the route from kubectl get routes I get nothing. Anyone experience with openfunctions or something similar who knows what is going on. I have not a lot of experience with kubernetes so lets hope this is not a dumb question. Thanks in advance and if there is more info needed just ask for it in the comments. Thanks!

If you have access from inside the network (so between pods) and no access from outer world, it could be an issue with firewall rules.
This article is a good beginning regarding firewall rules for Kubernetes in Google Cloud: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/firewall-rules
